# Merge button NOT greyed out, but can't merge cells

Tags: merge, cells

I see a lot of issues with the button being grey and not working. But what about when the button is not grey, the button centers text, but the cells do not merge. I have unlocked the cells.

Comment: What? Where? Which product? Which operating system? Which spreadsheet?

Answer (score -2):

I was able to "Center Across Selection" in the text formatting window, which was good enough for me. NOTE: this was in Microsoft Excel Windows 10

Comment: Please update your original question to indicate you're asking about Excel. A screenshot would be very helpful as well.